# How to determine what causes rogue key_up events

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, keyboard

I have a Samsung laptop running Windows 8.1 in front of me, which has the following symptoms:

1. When holding down the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key, the start menu opens, closes, opens, closes at a high rate
2. Holding down the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key causes the following events

   ```
   keyup    keyCode=17        which=17        charCode=0        
   keydown  keyCode=18        which=18        charCode=0        
   keyup    keyCode=17        which=17        charCode=0        
   keydown  keyCode=18        which=18        charCode=0        
   keyup    keyCode=17        which=17        charCode=0        
   keydown  keyCode=18        which=18        charCode=0        
   keyup    keyCode=17        which=17        charCode=0        
   keydown  keyCode=18        which=18        charCode=0        
   keyup    keyCode=17        which=17        charCode=0        
   keydown  keyCode=18        which=18        charCode=0        
   keyup    keyCode=17        which=17        charCode=0        
   keydown  keyCode=18        which=18        charCode=0        
   keyup    keyCode=17        which=17        charCode=0        
   keydown  keyCode=18        which=18        charCode=0        
   keyup    keyCode=17        which=17        charCode=0        
   keydown  keyCode=18        which=18        charCode=0        
   keyup    keyCode=17        which=17        charCode=0        
   keyup    keyCode=18        which=18        charCode=0
   ```

   When trying this on other PC's, the output is (as expected)

   ```
   keydown  keyCode=18        which=18        charCode=0        
   keydown  keyCode=18        which=18        charCode=0           
   keydown  keyCode=18        which=18        charCode=0        
   keydown  keyCode=18        which=18        charCode=0        
   keydown  keyCode=18        which=18        charCode=0        
   keyup    keyCode=18        which=18        charCode=0
   ```

   Note the "fake" key-up events.
3. The <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> key cannot be used to produce special symbols like <kbd>€</kbd>, <kbd>@</kbd> and <kbd>#</kbd>. When using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd> instead of <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>, these symbols can be produced.
4. Doing the same through an external USB keyboard causes the same issues.

All of these symptoms persist even when running in safe mode. How do I go about diagnosing the issue at hand?

Comment: You ask the user what they spilled on the keyboard. Then you replace the keyboard.

Comment: It does the exact same thing on an external USB keyboard. The keypresses do work when sent over teamviewer.

Comment: Is [Sticky Keys feature](https://www.isunshare.com/windows-8/turn-on-and-turn-off-sticky-keys-on-windows-8-8.1.html) enabled and turned on?